# What is wrong with this SQL statement for selecting columns with a condition

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I am trying to extract a few columns based on some conditions. I am getting a error.

Statement

```
SELECT deviceDetails.lastUpdatedDate connectionDetails.phoneNumber1 deviceDetails.simImea1 deviceDetails.simImea2 deviceDetails.model connectionDetails.latitude connectionDetails.longitude 
from connectionDetails c inner join deviceDetails d 
on (c.deviceUniqueIdentity == d.deviceUniqueIdentity && d.rowStatus=='0') 
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/merged.csv' 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Error

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.phoneNumber1 deviceDetails.simImea1 deviceDetails.simImea2 deviceDetails.model ' at line 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT deviceDetails.lastUpdatedDate,connectionDetails.phoneNumber1,deviceDetails.simImea1
 deviceDetails.simImea2,deviceDetails.model,connectionDetails.latitude, 
connectionDetails.longitude 
from connectionDetails c inner join deviceDetails d 
on (c.deviceUniqueIdentity = d.deviceUniqueIdentity && d.rowStatus='0') 
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/merged.csv' 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Answer (score 1):

Put commas between column names.

Answer (score 1):

In select statement the columns should be seperated by comma `,`

```
SELECT 
deviceDetails.lastUpdatedDate,
connectionDetails.phoneNumber1,
deviceDetails.simImea1,
deviceDetails.simImea2,
deviceDetails.model,
connectionDetails.latitude,
connectionDetails.longitude
from connectionDetails
```